# How to find mean and variance of population of flat probabilistic distribution

Tags: sample, population

I'm trying to understand the difference `sample variance` and `population variance` and how former converges to latter after increasing sample size. I found [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/unbiased-variance-visualization/1167453164) that visually show this. I'm unable to understand how did the variance and mean for the population was calculated.

I'm unable to calculate it because I think there would be infinitely many element in that range(`0-200`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an example of `discrete uniform distribution`. So formula for `mean` and `variance` given `a` and `b` is:

`Mean` = ${\frac{a+b}{2}}$

`Variance` = ${\frac  {(b-a+1)^{2}-1}{12}}$.

substituting `a = 0`, `b = 200`. we get `mean = 100` and `variance = 3366.66`.